# How to make js request from react?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, axios

I have a button **"Show more"** when I click on that, without rebooting, I want to load new objects

```
const UsersPageButton = ({ bottomUrl }) => {
  const userClick = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const page = bottomUrl.slice(-1);
    const axios = require('axios');
    const url = '/users'
    const data = { 'page': page };

    const options = {
      method: 'get',
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      data: data,
      url,
    }

    axios(options);
  };
  return (
    <a className="button" onClick={userClick} href={bottomUrl}>Show more</a>
  )

};
```

On this request, I get another pack of objects and already display using **index.js.erb**

```
$(".users-list").html("<%= j render 'users/users', users: @users %>")
```

But the request to the controller comes **as HTML**, therefore **index.js.erb** is not rendered.

How to send a **script** request (JS request) to render the **index.js.erb**?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass your axios response to component, that will render all the users that were fetched.

A better solution would be separating your axios request from button, leaving only onClick handler prop. E.g.:

```
  const userClick = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const page = bottomUrl.slice(-1);
    const axios = require('axios');
    const url = '/users'
    const data = { 'page': page };

    const options = {
      method: 'get',
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      data: data,
      url,
    }
    // Notice the 
    axios(options).then(response => this.setState({data: response.data});
  };

  return (
  <div>
    <UsersList data={data} />
    <UsersPageButton onClick={userClick} />
  </div>
  );
```